# Gaussian Mixture Models: Maximum Likelihood Estimation or Expectation Maximization?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution

As far as I know the usual method for estimating the parameters in GMM is EM. However, it is also possible to use maximum likelihood. What are the differences between these two methods? Why would one prefer either of them?

Comment: Why can't you directly compute the Maximum Likehood by setting the derivative to 0 and solving an equation system, but have to do it iteratively with EM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ML directly but as the priors of the different gaussians (usually called **latent variables**) are unknown, you'll probably find that your optimization objective is pretty hard. EM iterative method solves this intractability.

Suggested read:
https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes8.pdf

Comment: So, EM is almost always used in this case?

Comment: Yes, and as the number of gaussians in the mixture model grows, the probability of not using EM is reduced even further.

Comment: And do you know why gradient is used in Fisher vectors? Does it have to do with MLE?

Comment: This question is not related to your original question. Mark this question answered, ask another one and I'll answer there.

Answer (score 13):

Mehrin, you are in danger of creating a false dichotomy. EM is an optimisation technique that can be used to find maximum likelihood estimates and so the choice is not "one or the other".

In mixture models EM is often used to find MLEs or MAPs as it produces transparent algorithms.

Comment: You can, however, use MLE directly i.e. take the gradient of pdf w.r.t. the mixture parameters and use gradient ascent.

Comment: @Mehrin, yes, but the question title should probably be changed to "direct optimization versus expectation-maximization algorithm."  EM is an implementation of MLE.

Comment: @Mehrin you could do this for the means/variances - but the cluster assignment probabilities phis are constrained to the simplex (sum to 1, all non negative). It is a constrained optimization, and gradient descent won't work on it.

Comment: Hi @Mehrin, I will appreciate it if you could elaborate on you answers on how to use GD to optimize hierarchichal mixture models, where there is a liklihood and priors?